# Iterate through a nested list

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, nested-lists

I am attempting to iterate through a nested list in R, and can't quite get the function/for loop correct.

Sample of my data:

```
> str(waveforms)
List of 3
$ Sta2_Ev20:List of 7
..$ 1: num [1:10000] 5.88e-05 -2.84e-05 -5.50e-05 7.02e-05 1.90e-06 ...
..$ 2: num [1:10000] 2.61e-05 -2.14e-05 -2.02e-05 2.97e-05 5.94e-06 ...
..$ 3: num [1:10000] 1.08e-05 -4.12e-05 1.95e-05 3.03e-05 -4.55e-05 ...
..$ 4: num [1:10000] 2.45e-05 -1.23e-05 -1.53e-05 2.76e-05 3.07e-06 ...
..$ 5: num [1:10000] 2.29e-05 0.00 5.71e-06 -2.86e-05 5.71e-06 ...
..$ 6: num [1:10000] -1.01e-04 2.37e-05 2.08e-05 -5.93e-06 2.08e-05 ...
..$ 7: num [1:10000] 3.47e-05 -2.75e-05 0.00 1.45e-05 -1.45e-06 ...
$ Sta2_Ev21:List of 34
..$ 1 : num [1:10000] 1.35e-05 -3.46e-05 -3.46e-05 8.65e-05 -2.11e-05 ...
..$ 2 : num [1:10000] 5.68e-05 1.14e-05 -7.38e-05 2.27e-05 4.73e-05 ...
..$ 3 : num [1:10000] 8.21e-06 3.69e-05 -2.46e-05 1.64e-05 -8.21e-06 ...
..$ 4 : num [1:10000] 3.26e-05 -1.34e-05 -1.19e-05 8.90e-06 1.78e-05 ...
..$ 5 : num [1:10000] 2.43e-05 -3.00e-05 1.29e-05 2.86e-06 -1.00e-05 ...
..$ 6 : num [1:10000] -6.87e-06 2.34e-05 -2.34e-05 3.44e-05 -2.20e-05 ...
..$ 7 : num [1:10000] 1.23e-05 -5.75e-05 2.46e-05 1.23e-05 -2.74e-06 ...
..$ 8 : num [1:10000] -2.34e-05 -2.17e-05 1.83e-05 4.17e-05 -4.50e-05 ...
..$ 9 : num [1:10000] 3.34e-05 7.42e-06 -2.04e-05 7.42e-06 0.00 ...
etc...
```

REPRODUCIBLE DATA

```
Sta2_Evt1=list(a=runif(10000, min=-12, max=12), b=runif(10000, min=-12, max=12),c=runif(10000, min=-12, max=12)) 
Sta2_Evt2=list(a=runif(10000, min=-2, max=2), b=runif(10000, min=-2, max=2),c=runif(10000, min=-2, max=2))  
...  
waveforms=list(Sta2_Evt1,Sta2_Evt2,...))
binsize=5000
```

And so on.  What I need to do it iterate through each list within my list.  I tested the data on one of the "Sta#_Evt#" lists.  Previously, this code worked:

```
ch0=list()
for (i in seq_along(Sta2_Evt2)) {
  tempobj=head(Sta2_Evt2[[i]],n=binsize)
  name <- paste('click',names(Sta2_Evt2)[[i]],sep='')
  ch0[[name]] <- tempobj
}
```

This is simple, just extracting the first 5000 data points from each element. From this new list of elements (ch0), I was able to run multiple scripts to process my data.  However, now that I need to expand to include ALL my data, not just the test set I was originally working with, I can't figure out how to run iterations over nested lists (like waveform, above). When I run the code for 'ch0', for instance, over my nested 'waveform' list, it returns the same nested list.

I have tried a few methods: lapply, an additional for loop, llply. I think that maybe writing a function to complete my analysis, and then using llply. However, with this function:

```
mkChs=function(x,binsize) {for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  head(x[[i]],n=binsize)
}}
test=llply(waveforms,mkChs, binsize=5000)
```

It still does not work.  The new list 'test' comes back empty.

I've tried a nest for loop.

```
ch0=list()
for (i in seq_along(waveforms)) {
  a=list(names(waveforms)[[i]])
  b=for (j in seq_along(waveforms[i])) {
    tempobj=head(waveforms[[i]][[j]],n=binsize)
    name <- paste('click',seq_along(waveforms)[[i]][[j]]-1,sep='')
   a[[name]] <- tempobj
  }
name1 <- names(waveforms)[[i]]
ch0[[name1]] <- b
}
```

That returns the following:

```
str(ch0)
List of 3
$ Sta2_Ev20: num [1:5000] 5.88e-05 -2.84e-05 -5.50e-05 7.02e-05 1.90e-06 ...
$ Sta2_Ev21: num [1:5000] 1.35e-05 -3.46e-05 -3.46e-05 8.65e-05 -2.11e-05 ...
$ Sta2_Ev22: num [1:5000] 2.06e-05 3.44e-06 2.06e-05 -3.44e-05 0.00 ...
```

Not exactly what I am looking for. I'd rather not have a separate list per "Sta#_Evt#" to get this to run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a nested loop. Turns out my previous loop was missing a pair of parentheses!

```
ch0=list()
for (i in seq_along(waveforms)) {
  a=list()
  b=for (j in seq_along(waveforms[[i]])) {
    tempobj=head((waveforms[[i]])[[j]],n=binsize)
    name <- paste('click',seq_along((waveforms)[[i]])[[j]]-1,sep='')
    a[[name]] <- tempobj
  }
  name1 <- names(waveforms)[[i]]
  ch0[[name1]] <- a
}
```

In the `tempobj=head((waveforms[[i]])[[j]],n=binsize)` line of the for loop, I had neglected to put parentheses around `waveforms[[i]]`, and again when generating the names.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a minimal reproducible example which may get close to what you want

```
waveform <- list("a" = list('1' = c(1,2,3), '2' = c(4,5,6)),
                 "b" = list('1' = c(7,8,9), '2' = c(10,11,12))) 

# arbitrary function  
my_fun <- function(vec) {
  return(mean(vec))
}

# return list structure
r1 <- lapply(waveform, function (x) {
  lapply(x, my_fun)})

# return a two dimensional array
r2 <- sapply(waveform, function (x) {
  sapply(x, my_fun)})

str(r1)
# List of 2
# $ a:List of 2
# ..$ 1: num 2
# ..$ 2: num 5
# $ b:List of 2
# ..$ 1: num 8
# ..$ 2: num 11



r2
#   a  b
# 1 2  8
# 2 5 11
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  However, I think the issue is that I am not running statistics in my functions as you are.  I am trying to reorganize the data by splitting each vector 10000 elements long into further lists.  So this isn't applicable.